# If $\gcd(a,x)=1$ and $a|x^n-1$, then $n|\varphi(a)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

Does $\gcd(a,x)=1$ and $a|x^n-1$ imply that $n|\varphi(a)$? Where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function. Suppose that $n<\varphi(a)$.

Comment: What makes you think this is true? Could you share your thoughts on the question with us, in stead of only a question without any context?

Comment: In my previous question, someone said that if $\gcd(x, p)=\gcd(x, q)=1$, where $p$ and $q$ are some primes and $p|x^a-1$ and $q|x^a-1$, then $pq|x^a-1$ and by Euler's totient function $a|\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: This last part is false, as my answer shows. Also note that $a\mid x^n-1$ already implies that $\gcd(a,x)=1$, so this hypothesis is superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has no chance of even being remotely true. Let $a=2$ and let $x$ be an odd integer.

Then $\gcd(a,x)=1$ and $\varphi(a)=1$ and $a\mid x^n-1$ for any $n>0$, so certainly $n\nmid\varphi(a)$.

More generally, if $n\mid m$ then $x^n-1\mid x^m-1$, so if $a\mid x^n-1$ then there exist arbitrarily large $m$ such that $a\mid x^m-1$. So we certainly can't have $m\mid\varphi(a)$ in general.

For an example with $n<\varphi(a)$ let $a=7$ so that $\varphi(a)=6$. Then for $x=6$ and $n=4$ we get $$6^4-1=1295=5\times7\times37,$$
so $7\mid6^4-1$ but $4\nmid 6$.

Comment: There is the $n<\phi(a)$ condition, I think you missed that.

Comment: @Element118 : but it's still not true, since all we know from $x^n \equiv 1 \pmod a$ and $x < \phi(a)$ is that $ord_a(x) \ |\ n$ and $ord_a(x)\ |\  \phi(a)$ but if $ord_a(x) = \phi(a)/3$ and $n = 2 ord_a(x)$ then $n \not|  \ \phi(a)$

Comment: Seems right. Thanks for the example to clear up.

Comment: now $a = 13, \varphi(13) = 12$, $n = 8, x= 5$, $ord_{13}(5) = 4$ (since $5^2 \equiv - 1 \pmod{13}$) hence $5^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ is a counter-example